# Integrating Sign In with Azure Active Directory in .Net Core

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to integrate sign in option through Azure Active Directory with .net core application. I have been through Microsoft's blogs and I have been to the steps where user can login with Microsoft's account. But the ISSUE is

"It is always redirecting me to the login action method again." which loops me back to sign in screen.

Image for redirect URLS:
[image]

My Startup Class

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie()
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";


                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

            });
```

My Login account controller

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Search");

            var domainInfo = await _subdomainProvider.GetDomainInfoAsync(Request.Host.Value);
            if (domainInfo.LoginMethod == LoginMethod.AzureAD)
            {
                var redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Search");
                var properties = _signInManager
                    .ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(LoginMethod.AzureAD.ToString(), redirectUrl);
                return new ChallengeResult(LoginMethod.AzureAD.ToString(), properties);

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.Background = await GetRandomBackgroundAsync(domainInfo.LoginBackgrounds);
            }


            return View(new LoginModel
            {
                Language = GetLanguage(),
                ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
            });
        }
```

Login View

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
        <h2>@AccountStrings.Login_ExternalLogin_Title</h2>
        <div>

            @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn  login-provider @provider.DisplayName"
                        name="provider" value="@provider.Name"
                        title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">
                    @provider.DisplayName
                </button>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
```

Even added the redirection URL on azure portal to be redirected to action method i-e dashboard.but still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to integrate Azure AD with your .net core web application. If so, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) and the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

1. appsettings.json file

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<you tenant doamin>",
    "TenantId": "<>",
    "ClientId": "<>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

2. Add the following code to the startup.cs

```
  services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            //services.Configure<AzureADOptions>(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems you are using ASP.NET Core Identity with Azure AD login . If that is your scenario , you can set `CookieSchemeName` to `Identity.External` so that asp.net core identity can get the external user profile from external identity provider :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

});
```

Azure AD application setting :

```
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
        "TenantId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-4f08-b544-b1eb456f228d",
        "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-4717-9821-e4f718fbece4",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"
    },
```

Comment: This seems helpful. After applying this I am getting this error:

**InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.External'. The registered sign-in schemes are: Cookies, AzureAD, AzureADCookie. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Identity.External",...)?**

Comment: If using asp.net identity with Azure AD , you doesn't need to write your logic which loop the extenal schema and add to login page , you can directly redirect user to `https://localhost:xxxx/Identity/Account/Login` and it will list all the avalibale external identity provider , in there user can choose AAD .